# Reporting Services - using subreport from different RS folder

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reporting-services-2016

I have a main report and a subreport created in SSRS. On the report server (SQL Server Reporting Services) I have two folders:

```
Common
MainReports
```

The subreport is deployed in Common folder and the main report is deployed in MainReports folder.

How do I enable or change the report on Report Server to retrieve the subreport from Common folder?

The main report shows the subreport properly when both of them are in same folder, but when they are in separate folders I (naturally) get an "Subreport could not be shown" error.

Comment: I'm not sure you can do this directly from Visual Studio or Report Builder. WHat I normally do it have all the sub reports named as `_subMySubReport` etc. Then I run a script that sets all the reports named `_sub%` to hidden with something like `UPDATE Reportserver.dbo.[Catalog] set hidden = 1 where name like '_sub%'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use the following path defination ;

```
/Common/Subreportname/
```